# Dynamically displaying an image from XML with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I'm very new to HTML. 
I am trying to load an XML which contains image names and display it in a div dynamically.
I can see the image names but can't assing img a source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

xmlhttp.open("GET","resimler.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("pic");
i=0;

function displayFoto(){
ad=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ad")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("showFoto").innerHTML="img/" + ad;}

function next(){
if (i<x.length-1){
  i++;
  displayFoto();}}

function previous(){
if (i>0){
  i--;
  displayFoto();}}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayFoto()">
<div id='showFoto'><img id='showFoto'></img></div><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="previous()" value="<<" />
    <input type="button" onclick="next()" value=">>" />
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: It's hard to tell you what to do when we don't even know what the XML looks like. Also, your AJAX code doesn't look quite right to me. Shouldn't you have some sort of handler for `onreadystatechange` to know when the request is complete and the response is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("showFoto").src="img/" + ad;
```

this would help you to load image but i dont garanty about rest of the code. You better look for Loader frameworks and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kemal, just give a snipet of your xml and also the id for div and img tag is same, is that something you are unaware of it or just intentional

Comment: Oh, yeah I think thats a mistake now. 
Here is my xml, it works fine, I can get the content of XML right. I just dont know how to use that content as a img source. 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<vector>
    <pic>
        <ad>01-Wedding.jpg</ad>
        <txt>1</txt>
    </pic>
    <pic>
        <ad>02-Wedding.jpg</ad>
        <txt>1</txt>
    </pic>
    <pic>
        <ad>03-Wedding.jpg</ad>
        <txt>1</txt>
    </pic>
</vector>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function loadXMLDoc()
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                    var Image = "";
                    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE");

                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
                    {
                        Image = Image + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
                        var res = Image.split(" ");

                        var ii = res[i];
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = ii;
                        img.width = 150;
                        img.height = 100;

                        document.body.appendChild(img);
                    }

                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ll.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">

</body>
```